# Strange use of the past tense by Dr. Watson in the Sherlock series

Tags: grammar, tenses

I’m trying to correctly identify the reason why the past tense of ‘’to be’’ is used in the following context:

Sherlock Season 3 Episode 3

The scene:

Dr. Watson is about to enter a drug den. His wife spots some kind of weapon tucked into his trousers and the following dialogue takes place:

> – What is that?
>   – It’s a tyre lever.
>   – Why?
>   – ‘cos there **were** loads of smack heads in there and one of them might need help with a tyre.

The only guess I’ve got is that ‘were’ is used to express uncertainty and therefore add sarcasm, and the intended meaning is ’’there is a slight possibility that there may be a lot of smack heads in this drug den’’.

But I’m not sure if this is the right interpretation, as I’ve never come across this kind of tense use before.

Comment: Are you sure he didn't say "...there _are_ loads of smack heads..."

Comment: It's in the subtitles. I thought it could be a typo, but I kept on rewinding and listening again, and it seems like ''were'' is pronounced there indeed.

Comment: I have two sources that have him saying, "(Because) there's a load of smackheads in there, and one of them might need help changing a tire." ? I haven't seen episode 3, but there's a transcript [here](http://arianedevere.livejournal.com/67234.html). :)

Comment: Well if he has not yet gone in so how does he know it's full of smack-heads? It seems like he had been there before and "there **were** loads of smack heads in there (at that time) and (now) one of them might need help with a tyre."

Comment: Subtitles are usually produced automatically, and even if they're not, they are not faultlessly proof-read. *There're* sounds like *there were* but probably means *there are*. I'd need to watch the episode again to be sure, though.

Comment: I have no idea why Conan Doyle would have used 'were', if indeed he did. But the important point is that it does not reflect any special idiomatic use, of which anyone here seems to be aware.

Comment: Going by the comments, it's a typo, for sure. @AndrewLeach 's comment may well count as the answer - automatic subtitle generation explains it all.

Comment: @ alena: You shouldn't assume "were" is impossible here. I'm not going to watch the thing to establish the *exact* context, but given Dr. Watson refers to the location as "there", he's not actually *in* it at the time of speaking. In order to know about the smackheads at all, he must have either seen or been told about that *at some earlier point in time*, so it's not unreasonable to reflect that in his choice of tense. Akin to *"He asked my name so I told him it was FumbleFingers"* - the fact that this is *still* true doesn't mean I can't use past tense.

Comment: @Andrew: TV subtitles are produced automatically for things like the news and weather, which are effectively "real-time". But even in those contexts, where the actual speakers are going out of their way to enunciate *very* clearly, those subtitles are rubbish (the BBC usually have a human "auto-correcting" a few seconds behind real time). Subtitles for BBC drama are normally accurate - it's subtitles for old films on the Internet that are sometimes awful, because they're often created by non-native speakers (the original movie company never having produced any themselves).

Comment: -1 I didn't find it *strange* until you tried to 'explain' why it should not be. This is not about language, but logic. Think again, alena, and *were* makes sense.

Comment: @WS2: The TV series is not written directly by Conan Doyle. Indeed I remember not a single use in the canon of the word *smackheads*.

Comment: @Kris I would very much appreciate if you could elaborate your thought. Logic resides in language – you think with the language, it's the thinking tool. Please bear in mind that if one is not a native speaker of a language (as myself), he or she may well fail to grasp even the basic meaning – and therefore not be able to see the logic behind it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, Dr. Watson was told about the place earlier. Can therefore this choice of tense count as the emphasis on the fact that he was told about the place by someone else rather than this information being some kind of general knowledge?

Comment: @ alena: I suppose you could do, but don't overanalyse the significance of the tense choice. In my first comment I could just as easily have said *"I told him my name **is** FumbleFingers"*. Anglophones only really have two verb tenses, and we're not as careful about using them as you might imagine if your own language works differently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. I didn't know that. I've always thought that choosing "the wrong" tense is very painful to a native ear.

Comment: @ alena: In certain cases that's true. But as well as my earlier example, note that it's perfectly normal to say things like *"Tomorrow I go to work in the morning, then I have the afternoon off"*. We don't always use "future tense" for future activities. I would strongly urge you to consider using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for any future questions - you'll probably get better answers more targeted to non-native speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just rewatched the relevant scene and Dr Watson's "'Cos there were..." makes no sense at all if he hasn't been to the crack house before (as confirmed by his conversation with Isaac's mother). It just looks like a script continuity error to me - they changed the action slightly and didn't correct the script.

Comment: I just rewatched it too. cos there're loads of smack heads in there and one of them might need help with a tyre.